# Script fails after page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Got a refresh botton on a form (using jquery mobile). After pressing that button the page is refreshed but the script (on the page) fails to run (on action clicking submit). Here is how the page looks:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" id="refresh" name="actionType" value="Refresh" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="actionType" value="Submit" />
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")    

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#submit').click(function () {
     alert('Here');
   });
</script>
```

The refresh is implemented as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string actionType)
    {
        if (actionType == "Refresh")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm don't know how the jQuery mobile page refresh can affect your script. Maybe it does something with your submit ids...

But you can try to use a different selector: e.g subscribe on the `input` elements which has the type submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
     alert('Here');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But why does selection '#submit' work without a refresh?

Comment: To be honest I don't know... You menetioned that you use jQuery mobile so I guess it is related to jQuery mobile although your sample code doesn't contain any jQuery mobile related parts.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to do whatever you want inside document.ready():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
     alert('Here');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you subscribing to the `.submit()` event of the form instead of the `.click()` event of submit buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('form').submit(function () {
     alert('Here');
   });
</script>
```